# Terminal displays empty space after international characters

Tags: special-characters, xfce4-terminal

I use Ubuntu Studio 22.04.1 LTS

Since a while, I can see a weird empty space after each time there is an international (or special) character in the screen of the Terminal Panel.

Please, see the image.
[image]

As you can see, after the folder names: "Imágenes" (Images), "Música" (Music) and "Vídeos" (Videos) there is an empty space after the characters "á" "ú" and "í"

Why?

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the config option "Ambiguous-width characters" (it's probably under the Compatibility or Advanced tab – I don't have an xfce4-terminal installed right now to check it). Set it to "narrow".

(Also complain at the Unicode Consortium why these characters are defined to have ambiguous width rather than narrow, IMO it makes no sense whatsoever.)

Comment: Thank you so much @egmont! Problem solved.